# getting trouble with running program in c on linux

Tags: c, linux, gcc, execl

why I am not succeed

```
 int main(char* name,int arg0,int arg1)
 {
   name = "/u/e2014/Desktop/os/Prog.c";
   arg0 = 0;
   arg1 = 1;

   char my_args[3];
   my_args[0] = arg0;
   my_args[1] = arg1;
   my_args[2] = NULL;
   execl(name,m_args);

   return(0);
  }
```

[image]

I want that my program will execute the program in the path "name".
Right now its do nothing.

I am not understand where is my mistake?
I program in C on linux, and compile it with gcc

Thanks a lot!!

Comment: What on earth were you *expecting* this program to do??

Comment: to execute the program in name = "/u/e2014/Desktop/os/Prog.c"

Comment: You have the wrong declaration of `main`, and the wrong parameters for `execl`. What parameters are you supposed to pass to that other program?

Comment: path of file like: "/u/e2014/Desktop/os/Prog.c" and two integers

Comment: There are so many problems with this code that I'm inclined to close-vote on account of it being too broad. You can't execute C code directly. It has to be compiled. You can't mess around with the signature of the `main()` function. You clearly haven't read the documentation for `execl()`....

Comment: Please read [images considered harmful to S.O. postings](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-may-i-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557) and refrain from embedding images in your Qs in the future. Good luck.

Answer (score 1):

gcc has 3 different signature for main function

```
int main(void);
int main(int argc, char* argv[]);
int main(int argc, char *argv[], char *envp[]);
```

Your main function doesn't match either of these. therefore compiler error.

For your case you can use the 2nd signature with a small modification.

```
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    char *path;
    int int1, int2;

    path = argv[1];
    int1 = atoi(argv[2]);
    int2 = atoi(argv[3]);
}
```

Comment: ok, so now its more complicated. i want to pass to main : path of file and two integers. with this signature, i am not see how i can do that... :/

Comment: i need to pass two integers to main: this signature its o.k? :    int main( int argc, int argc1,  char **argv)   because i am searching for information about this signature with 2 parameters and i am not find

Answer (score 0):

First you are passing wrong parameter in int main(). main() has at least 3 args only.

int main(int argc, char*argv[], char *envp[]);

To execute your program you should use execvp() because you passing arrey of char* not command-line arguments via a variable-argument.

difference between execl and execv?

**L vs V: whether you want to pass the parameters to the exec'ed program as

L: individual parameters in the call (variable argument list): execl(), execle(), execlp(), and execlpe()
     V: as an array of char* execv(), execve(), execvp(), and execvpe()**

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>

int main(int argc,char*argv[])
 {
   char *name = "/root/a.out";
   char *arg0 = "0";
   char *arg1 = "1";

   char *my_args[4];

   my_args[0] = name;
   my_args[1] = arg0;
   my_args[2] = arg1;
   my_args[3] = NULL;
  execvp(my_args[0],my_args);

   return(0);
  }
```

Comment: this signature will compiled: int main(int argc, int argc1, char*argv[])  because i need two integers

Comment: @LilachDery no it will not work. if you want to get integer then you have to convert int from **argv as samuel Robert did in 2 answer of your question.